# Load earlier msg of conversation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello I am making a chat application. What I want when the user scrolls to the top a show history/show more button appears and when I click on it should load earlier messages but in batches. Since, multiple users can chat I am facing problem in storing the last id of the fetched msg. Here is my concept

When a user clicks on a online user, then first 10 msgs are loaded from the database. When users scrolls to the top show more button appears. If he clicks that button then using the id of last fetched row I am again fetching next 10 rows which are less than previous id. But since there are multiple users I need to store different ids. How should I do that. Here is my jquery and php code.

```
$('#m-'+id).scroll(function() {

                    var pos = $('#m-'+id).scrollTop();
                    if (pos == 0) {
                        $("#h2-"+id).after("<div id = 'showmore-"+id+"'>Show More</div>");
                    }
                    else{
                        $("#showmore-"+id).hide();
                    }

                    $("#showmore-"+id).click(function(){
                            $.ajax({

                            url: "loadmessage.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data:{
                                'sender': sender,
                                'receiver': receiver,
                            },
                            //SELECT * FROM `messagse` WHERE ((sender_id = 1 AND receiver_id = 2) OR (sender_id = 1 AND receiver_id = 2)) AND (id < 36) order by id desc LIMIT 20
                            success: function(response){
                                var result = JSON.parse(response);
                                console.log("Result is " +result);
                                //result.sort();

                                for(var i = result.length-1; i >=0; i--){
                                    $("#m-"+id).prepend('<p class = "shout_msg">' +result[i]+ '</p>');
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    })
                });
```

PHP code

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['sender']) AND isset($_REQUEST['receiver']) ){

    $sender = $_REQUEST['sender'];
    $receiver = $_REQUEST['receiver'];

        require_once 'dc_chat.php';
        $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

        $result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT id from users where username LIKE '{$sender}'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result); 
        $sender_id = $row[0]; 

        $result = $mysqli -> query("SELECT id from users where username LIKE '{$receiver}'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result); 
        $receiver_id = $row[0]; 


        $sql = $mysqli -> query("SELECT username from users where id in (select sender_id from messagse where sender_id = $sender_id )");

        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($sql); 
        $name = $row[0];    


        //$sql = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * from messagse where (sender_id = $sender_id AND receiver_id = $receiver_id) OR (sender_id = $receiver_id AND receiver_id = $sender_id) ");  

        $sql = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM `messagse` WHERE (sender_id = $sender_id AND receiver_id = $receiver_id) OR (sender_id = $receiver_id AND receiver_id = $sender_id) order by id desc LIMIT 5");  

            $arr = array();
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                                $arr[] = $name." ". $row[3]." ".$row[4];
                            }
                echo json_encode($arr);
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> But since there are multiple users I need to store different ids. How should I do that.

Rather than order by the id of the table you should order by the id of the user you are retrieving past messages for.  That way you can limit it to the number you want, e.g. LIMIT 5.  Then after that you can LIMIT 5,5 etc.

Comment: Should I make two ajax call for it. One to retrieve messages on load and other for show more ?

Comment: Sure.  You'll need to keep track of what 'offset' you are currently at with the SQL query results.  That way the next AJAX call can send the current offset and the SQL query can use it in the LIMIT part, e.g. LIMIT 5,5 then LIMIT 10,5 then LIMIT 15,5 and so on.  At some point the query will return no results and you will know you have reached the end of the history.

Comment: Can you show me example how do it in my existing code. I am new to this.