# Laravel 5.3 - Eloquent get paginated collection from certain point with id?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

For a blog post, given `post_id` of `4` which has `1000` comments, I can get `comment_id` of `400` using eloquent like this:

`$comment = Comment::where('id', 400)->where('post_id', 4)->first();`

The question is, how can I get for that same post, the chunk of 10 comments starting with `comment_id` `400` with the previous 9 comments (for a total of 10).

This is for pagination starting from a certain point in the comments, in this case `400`. If there are any comments before/after `400` for this post, I would need the previous/next pagination urls if they exist.

So for example, `400` has more comments around it for this post, so I should get back comments with `comment_id` `400 - 390` from eloquent, with this pagination (pseudo code):

```
next_page_url: "http://laravel.app?page=61",
prev_page_url: "http://laravel.app?page=59"
```

What would the eloquent query to handle this situation in laravel be?

Comment: Why based on the comment id? Trying to understand the use-case.

Comment: @Oddman [Here is the use-case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798427/load-earlier-msg-of-conversation), but looking to do it in Laravel. Instead of 2 pagination links, maybe one to load comments `400`-`410` is fine (this works), but if an immediate previous comment id exists for the `post_id` of `4`, for example `300` exists as the previous comment on this `post_id`, how to know about it so we can show a load earlier comments button. Is there a way to handle it once with eloquent? How do you suggest the best way to handle this is?

Comment: Yup, so if you want next/back links, you could just do a query that finds the previous 10 records (ie. ID < 400) and return true or false by doing ->exists(). You could then show the appropriate pagination link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would do it based on ID - I'd simply push it back 400 spots. However, here:

```
Comment::where('id', '<', 400)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
```

This will get you the 10 previous comments.

Comment: Also, what about the previous 10 comments if they exits as a url? I did it like this: `$comments = Comment::where('id', '<=', 400)->where('post_id', 4)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);` and this gives the result set, but only the next url is shown, no previous url. I would need to know if there is previous items with pagination url to fetch those if needed to load more previous/next comments from the `400` id point.